# What vCard formats/versions and encodings are supported for import?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, import, vcard, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have tried to import vCard files using default Contacts app in Samsung Galaxy S6 ([details here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/9381/9510)), but I am not sure about format required (vCard version supported) and Encoding to be used.

I have used `Windows-1250` encoding and it worked but all the special characters were imported as `?`.  When using `UTF-8` it failed to import completely. What is the recommended character encoding and recommended vCard format/version?

Currently my vCard file looks like this with Windows-1250 encoding:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
NAME:XXXX Günzel
N:Günzel;XXXXX;;;
TEL;CELL:+XXXXXXXXX
END:VCARD
```

Comment: Have you specified the charset with your vcard records? See [here](http://microformats.org/wiki/vcard-implementations) for examples.

Comment: No I did not... Should I? What is the default charset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not really an Android question, but assuming you were asking "how can I import this vCard file correctly into my Android address book": Some adjustments might be required to the vCard file. I found a specification summary [in this Github issue comment](https://github.com/sabre-io/vobject/issues/41#issuecomment-19756342):

> 1. vCard 2.1 is US-ASCII by default. Individual properties can be overridden with the `CHARSET=` parameter.
> 2. vCard 3.0 *requires* the mimetype to include a character set, e.g. `Content-Type: text/vcard; charset=ISO-8859-1`.
> 3. vCard 4.0 is *always* UTF-8.

Giving an example for 1., taken from [this article](http://microformats.org/wiki/vcard-implementations#MSOutlook2k3_N):

```
BEGIN:VCARD
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8:Mr. Dr. John Maurice Benjamin Doe Ph.D.\, J.D.
N;CHARSET=UTF-8:Doe;John;Maurice,Benjamin;Mr.,Dr.;Ph.D.,J.D.
END:VCARD
```

Further readings include [RFC 6350](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350) :)

Comment: So when I have 3.0 version vCards with UTF-8 encoding, then I do not need to do anything, I suppose? `The charset (see [RFC3536] for internationalization terminology) for
   vCard is UTF-8 as defined in [RFC3629].  There is no way to override
   this.  It is invalid to specify a value other than "UTF-8" in the
   "charset" MIME parameter (see Section 10.1).`

Comment: That's how I would read it, yes. Not that I've played with it, though :)

Comment: Seems I had two invalid characters at the beginning of the file created by C#, will check it later.

Comment: [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)? :) Have that issue quite often with SQL scripts on Oracle. Even with charset being UTF8, SQL*Plus cannot handle the BOM at the beginning of files (they must be saved as "UTF8 without BOM"). Not sure if that's the case here, though.

Comment: Yes BOM. Your answer was useful, thank you, will give it a try but the phone is not mine so it will take me a while.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional information based on comments, **most Android only supports vCard 2.1 as of Android 12, while vCard 3.0 might be supported by some, but no support for vCard 4.0**.

Dan wrote:

> As of Android N / Nougat / 7.0, the AOSP Contacts app can *only* import vCard **2.1** (which is also the format it exports). Any deviation from the vCard 2.1 format, including just changing the version identifier, will cause it to fail to import. - [source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106888/what-vcard-formats-versions-and-encodings-are-supported-for-import#comment252162_106901)
>
> [...]. I'm unsure if it's device- or ROM-specific and I can't find any particular source code to demonstrate it. [...] - [source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106888/what-vcard-formats-versions-and-encodings-are-supported-for-import#comment252191_106901)

DJCrashdummy wrote:

> sadly i have to confirm that shockingly still only vCard 2.1 is exported and only vCard 2.1 and 3.0 can be imported. - still **no support for vCard 4.0**! - [source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106888/what-vcard-formats-versions-and-encodings-are-supported-for-import#comment262207_106901)

Suncatcher wrote:

> [...] the situation hasn't changed since 2018 to 2022 unfortunately. Am writing this from Android 12 and it is still vCard 2.1 :( - [source](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106888/what-vcard-formats-versions-and-encodings-are-supported-for-import#comment335580_106901)