# How can I import a VCARD file (contact information) via a QR code into Android contacts?

Tags: contacts, qr-code, vcard

I would like to generate a QR code for my contact information to put on a website or my phone to show people. They should be able to scan it and import it automatically to their phone contacts. All I have found on the internet were solutions converting a VCARD text into a QR code. QR code scanners parse it as a text (scan works) but they are not able to parse it as contact information and pass it on the contacts app to be imported. I wonder how to manage this.

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=utf-8:Doe;John;;;
FN;CHARSET=utf-8:John Doe
ORG;CHARSET=utf-8:Dunder Mifflin
TITLE;CHARSET=utf-8:Manager
URL;WORK:dunder.com
EMAIL;WORK:john@dunder.com
TEL;CELL:+15551122334
ADR;WORK;CHARSET=utf-8:;;;Scranton;;;USA
END:VCARD
```

[image: example qr code]

Edit: hosting the VCF file with the correct mime type let's you download the file and import it. But this is unnecessarily cumbersome. I think that a direct import from the QR code should be possible.

Comment: Might be related: [What vCard formats/versions and encodings are supported for import?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/106888/44325)

Comment: Are you open to other formats?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeCard_(QR_code) is more compact and works for me.

Comment: It was definitely worth a try. Turns out that like a VCard some apps can recognize it while the camera app wasn't but the suggested app can also parse MeCard. Nevertheless, compacted code is of course better, therefore MeCard has a clear advantage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Just as a clarification for the other answers:*

This will depend on the app you use to scan the code - that app must support the VCARD format.

On recent Android versions (since Android 8, I believe) the standard camera app supplied by Google or the manufacturer usually supports QR codes, and also supports the VCARD format - so if you use stock Android, the camera app should work.

If your camera app does not support VCARD QR codes (for example the app in some versions of LineageOS), you can use a dedicated code scanning app which does. Some examples:

- QR Scanner (PFA), available in Google Play and also [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner/)
- Barcode Scanner, available [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/com.atharok.barcodescanner/)

Answer (score 3):

On recent Android versions the camera app has a built-in QR code reader. If you point the camera on the QR code a small text containing the contact name `John Doe` - as shown in the screenshot (from a Pixel4a running Android 13).

If the user taps on the name a dialog opens that asks what to do with the contact, e.g. adding it to the default address book (Google Contacts).

[image: Camera app on vcard QR code]

Comment: My lineageos camera app has the integrated QR code scanner as well but it does not offer an option to import into contacts. I downloaded another scanner application, this did not manage either. It is often recognized as "TEXT". There are Android users without Google as well.

Comment: @VPNer: Yes, it depends on the app you use. I added a clarifying answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have by chance stumbled upon this app on F-Droid, which can import it.
https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.secuso.privacyFriendlyCodeScanner/

It appears that the Vcard and the QR code were fine but LineageOS integrated scanner and another app I tried were not able to recognize a VCard.